# Backup for SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, sharepoint

I am trying to create a full backup of a SQL Azure database created as the result of

creating an Access 2013 web app.

The resulting SQL Azure is on our O365 SharePoint server and we can access it in SSMS by following the instructions from Access. We can see the tables but cannot create a backup or create views.  I cannot change the firewall settings.

This database is not your regular SQL Azure that would have been the result of creating a database, the database was created for us behind the scenes by MSFT.

Whenever I right click the database the firewall settings tell me that I don't have access.  Ok this is all fine but I need a backup.

I have full admin rights but cannot even figure out where the SQL Azure database resides on our O365 Sharepoint.

Is there a script that I can execute to copy all the tables and views (I'm not interested in system tables or views) from this handicapped SQL Azure database to a regular SQL Database?

Clarification

1. I created an Access web app on our O365 SharePoint site starting from Access 2013 (an Access 2013 web app requires SharePoint)
2. This in turn creates an Access web app front end and a SQL Azure back end, which I will call SQLAzureHidden.  This is not a user selection, MSFT created the Azure db.
3. The Access web app front end works like a charm, no issues
4. I don’t know where the SQLAzureHidden is located, it must be somewhere on our SP site but well hidden

**5.    I started without an Azure subscription because this is not required to create an Access 2013 web app. However, even a free Azure subscription linked to our SP site does NOT show SQLAzureHidden when I open the management portal**

6. I can only access our SQLAzureHidden using SSMS with the credentials copied below
   a.  ckj99mk65b.database.windows.net 
   b.  db_326bc9d4_2c7c_4de4_95e0_e6981f699a76
   c.  db_326bc9d4_2c7c_4de4_95e0_e6981f699a76_ExternalWriter
   d.  PWD: xxxxxxx
7. The above credentials are created in Access 2013
8. In SSMS I cannot change the firewall settings after accessing SQLAzureHidden with the above credentials  because some stored procedures are missing and some system views will not run because they are locked
9. Result: I fail to create a backup for our SQLAzureHidden and I cannot create any reports, views, or stored procedures in SSMS against SQLAzureHidden

Comment: why do you keep refereing to Office365? Azure SQL databases need to be managed through your Azure subscription ... so you first need to connect to your azure SQL management portal and create a firewall rule there allowing your current location to access the DB (although that connections shoud already be existing,since you can connect to it through SSMS)

Comment: I have edited my original post because the add comments does not havee enough space